# How these two adresses can be different ?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have a stucture

```
typedef struct    s_block
{
  size_t          size;
  struct s_block  *next;
  struct s_block  *back;
  int             free;
  void            *data;
}                 t_block;
```

And I initialise it this way:

```
int       createHeader()
{
    void  *data;
    data = sbrk(BLOCK_SIZE + (sizeof(t_block) * 2));
    header = data;
    header->next = header;
    header->back = header;
    header->size = 0;
    createNewBlock(data + sizeof(t_block), BLOCK_SIZE + sizeof(t_block), 0);
    return 0;
}

void  *createNewBlock(void *beginAddress, size_t size, int free)
{
  printf("%d\n", size);
  t_block *newBlock;
  printf("first %p\n", beginAddress);
  printf("addr : %p\n", beginAddress + size);
  newBlock = beginAddress;
  newBlock->back = header->back;
  newBlock->next = header;
  newBlock->size = size;
  newBlock->free = free;
  newBlock->data = beginAddress + sizeof(t_block);
  header->back->next = newBlock;
  header->back = newBlock;
  header->size++;
  show_alloc_mem();
  return newBlock->data;
}
```

When I display `beginAddress` in `createNewBlock` , the address given is good, and when I display the adress of `beginAddress + size`, it gives me the right adress :

```
140
first 0x18f9028
addr : 0x18f90b4
```

But when I enter in my function `show_alloc_mem()`

```
void show_alloc_mem()
{
  t_block *tmp;

  tmp = header->next;
  printf("break : %p\n", header);
  while (tmp != header)
  {
    if (tmp->free == 1)
      printf("%p - %p : %d bytes\n", tmp, tmp + tmp->size, (int)tmp->size);
    else
      printf("free: %p - %p : %d bytes\n", tmp, tmp + tmp->size, (int)tmp->size);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}
```

Strange behaviour happens.
The header adress and tmp adresses are correct. But the address of `tmp + size` isn't.

```
break : 0x18f9000
free: 0x18f9028 - 0x18fa608 : 140 bytes
```

Have you got an idea why ?

Comment: Did you notice that the new difference is *exactly* 40 * 140?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing pointer arithmetic, expecting it to behave like integer arithmetic.

The expression `tmp + tmp->size` evaluates to `(int)tmp + sizeof(t_block)*( (int)tmp->size )` because you're adding an integer (`tmp->size`) to a pointer to a structure (`tmp` is of type `t_block*`).

Comment: IOW, the number you're adding gets multiplied by the `sizeof` the destination pointer's value type before being added. (This should be a basic feature of any introductory text on pointer arithmetic, I would hope.)

Comment: Ok thanks I understand now. So I solved this by casting my tmp variable to void *

Comment: @DimitriDanilov - that will work with GCC and some other compilers, but is non-standard, as standard C does not support arithmetic on `void *` pointers. You can use `char *` instead for standards compliance, although that may require more explicit pointer type casting in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You use two different pointer arithmetic:

- one with `void *`
- one with `t_block *`

Your compiler permits you to do arithmetic on `void *` but it is excluded from the standard. Some compilers (yours) use *natural* arithmetic on `void *`, so in the first expression it calculates `BaseAdressValue+size` while in the second `BaseAddressValue+40*size` (40 is the size of your structure, five 8-bytes pointers, you are on a 64 bits pointer platform).